# jenkins: Find the triggering user of a job for the build-script

Tags: jenkins, slack

We're using Jenkins and Slack.
I'm trying to setup a slack notification about a build, and I would like the notifucation to include more information - so I resort to the custom message.

I found about `$GIT_BRANCH` and `$BUILD_NUMBER` and `$JOB_NAME` and other interesting guys, and put them to use.

But I lack a way to mention the cause that triggered the build - be it a polling on the scm, or a user that pressed ***build now***. 
The later is of **extreme importance** - especially in jobs that deploy to a target environment...

Can anybody recommend me a way to detect the triggering cause and add it to the custom message?

BTW - I'd want this information not only for slack notification.
I'd like to add this information to a signature file that we add to every artifact (as well as other things)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Build User Vars Plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin

You will have the variables:

- BUILD_USER – full name of user started build,
- BUILD_USER_FIRST_NAME – first name of user started build,
- BUILD_USER_LAST_NAME – last name of user started build,
- BUILD_USER_ID – id of user started build.

*If you want to get it from other job you can use the below URL:

http://[jenkins-server]/job/[job-name]/[build-number]/api/xml?xpath=(//action/cause/shortDescription)

It will directly return the line:

< shortDescription>Started by user foobar< /shortDescription>